# How to make a view in ConstraintLayout to be bigger than its parent?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have an Activity with ConstraintLayout, and a view in it:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".presentation.MainActivity">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/backgroundView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/main_background" />
```

I want this view to be bigger than its parent for, for example, `200dp` by each side.

On iOS I can just constraint it by (-Npt, -Npt, Npt, Npt) (left, top, right, bottom) to achieve this (on this screen target view is background view with pattern image):

[image]

But how to correctly do it on Android with ConstraintLayout

Comment: That's not usually done in Android. The closest thing we have ever done for that involved negative margins, and AFAIK those are not supported with `ConstraintLayout`.

Comment: @CommonsWare yep, negative margins do no work.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by establishing two 200dp x 200dp *Space* widgets outside the bounds of the *ConstraintLayout*. (This works, but I am not necessarily recommending its use. My only objection would be that it is kinda hackish.)

Create two space widgets that are 200dp x 200dp. Constrain the lower right corner of one to the upper left corner of the *ConstraintLayout* and the upper left corner of the other widget to the bottom right corner of the layout. Now constrain your view to the outer boundaries of these *Space* widget. You view will not stretch `200dp` outside the boundary of the *ConstraintLayout* on all sides.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/topLeft"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"/>

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/bottomRight"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/backgroundView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/main_background"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/bottomRight"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/bottomRight"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/topLeft"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/topLeft" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

In the image below, you can see the faint outline of the *Space* widgets.

[image]